# Endless loop doesn't work, compiled with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

When I add an endless loop to my, code it doesn't work. It just runs and does nothing.

For example, this code doesn't print `"hello"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello");
    while(1){

    }

    return 0;
}
```

but this code prints "hello".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello");
    //while(1){ 
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

How can I add a `while(1)` loop to my code?

Comment: You need to flush the buffer with a new line.  `printf("hello\n")`

Comment: " it just run and do nothing." what do you expect empty loop to do rather than nothing?

Comment: Why do you want an empty `while(1)` loop?

Comment: i want something in it. but it is just for example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux your comment got some ticks but to me the link was a TL;DR in this context. The question is about buffer discharge to ouput. Why are you saying an empty loop is *undefined behaviour*? Is it because an optimising compiler does not know whether to reject the loop?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's true in C++ but not in C.  In C an infinite loop whose controlling condition is constant is well-defined.  (Some C compilers, incorrectly, apply the C++ rule to C, see e.g.  https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=965 .)

Comment: PS I hate optimising compilers. My tutor advised me: don't let the compiler do the work for you. Since C is just above assembler, I would use another language if I didn't want control of my code. I *like* crafting my code.

Comment: @zwol The question was tagged c++ at the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane Note that the question was tagged c++ at the time of my comment. In that context, since all path can be shown to have undefined behavior, a compiler could optimize out the output in the name of speed. Coming from a c++ background, *"don't let the compiler do the work for you."* is inexcusable blasphemy of the highest order, but I guess things are different in the c community. Different languages, different goals.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess things are somewhat similar with C compilers now.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Even in C, there is a substantial population of programmers who want the compiler to do the work for them. Many are refugees from FORTRAN :-)

Comment: every programmer was newcommer someday @FrançoisAndrieux :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I made a brave attempt at C++ some time ago, but didn't like it. I was advised to change the way I think to be able use C++. That told me it fails in the primary requirement for a computer language: to bridge the gap between the way people think, and the way computers work. Things have come on a long way since.

Comment: @WeatherVane Trying to develop with c++ but with a c mindset leads to "programming in c with classes", the worst of both worlds. In my experience, the mindsets required to work with c and c++ are very different and it's challenging for professionals that are familiar with one to adopt the idiosyncrasies of the other. I feel c++ bridges the gap between how people think and computer very well, though it's features are geared towards helping developers express intent rather than detail. If you want to continue the discussion, we should migrate it to a chat as it's no longer about the question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you for the input, my last comment was not so much about idiosyncrasies but hierarchy of data structures and inheritance, which seemed to be upside down to the way I wanted to work. Too late here to go to chat sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for example in this code, doesn't print "hello".

It is because of the *buffering*.

You can call `fflush(stdout)` just after the `printf()` in order to flush the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(1){

    }

    return 0;
}
```

In your second case the buffer is flushed at program's termination.

Comment: It should be noted that the output buffer can also be flushed by terminating the print line with a line feed: `printf("hello\n")`, in which case the `fflush(stdout)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @lurker That may depend. For example, if `STDOUT_FILENO` is redirected to a file, it won't.

Comment: Yes, that's worth noting, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

If what you want, to start with, is to print "hello" infinitely, then you need something like this. It puts a print and flush *inside* the infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("hello");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```